# How to exclude certain variable from the Feature code?

Tags: i18n-l10n, features

In my Feature I wanted to add the multilingual `path_breadcrumbs_home_link_title` for `en` and `de`, but when generating the feature by including the `realm_variables` there is the `site_name` and `site_slogan` in the `en` array included too.

The `site_name` is a mandatory field, so I can not just leave it empty.

The generate file looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_variable_realm_default_variables().
 */
function foo_variable_realm_default_variables() {
  $realm_variables = array();
  $realm_variables['language']['de'] = array(
    'path_breadcrumbs_delimiter' => '»',
    'path_breadcrumbs_home_link_title' => 'Startseite',
  );
  $realm_variables['language']['en'] = array(
    'path_breadcrumbs_delimiter' => '»',
    'path_breadcrumbs_home_link_title' => 'Home',
    'site_name' => 'Demo Site',
    'site_slogan' => '',
  );
  return $realm_variables;
}
```

The site name would overwrite all the site names of any already deployed Drupal site.

I don't understand why it doesn't appear in the `de` array even while site name is set there too.

How can I get rid of this?

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hook_features_export_alter` would allow you to alter the final array of Component names to be exported, just prior to the rendering of defaults.

This allows feature modules a final say in whether or not certain Components are exported.

However the Components' actual data cannot be altered by this hook, so I'm not sure if that actually helps.

Example:

```
function hook_features_export_alter(&$export, $module_name) {
  // Example: do not allow the page content type to be exported, ever.
  if (!empty($export['features']['node']['page'])) {
    unset($export['features']['node']['page']);
  }
}
```